# WebMvcTest, exclude Repository interfaces from test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

### Setup

In my Spring Boot 2.7 application I've registered a simple ViewController using ViewControllerRegistry, so have no dedicated Controller for the start page:

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");    
    }
```

In my test class I try to filter out some Spring data JPA repository interfaces that are extending CrudRepository:

```
    @WebMvcTest(  
excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,  
classes = CrudRepository.class)})  

    class HomeControllerTest {
        
        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
        @Test
        public void testHomePage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
        }
    }
```

I cannot start up the context needed for `@WebMvcTest` as I use these JPA repository interfaces in other tests and they are picked up.
They currently all look like this:

```
public interface EntityNameRepository extends CrudRepository<EntityName, Long>
```

## Happens

The ApplicationContext fails to load and the test fails because of it.

## Tried this

I can add the repositories with `@MockBean` and ignore them which makes tests pass, but I'd prefer that these weren't loaded into the ApplicationContext at all when running this test.

That's what I attempted to achieve with the excludeFilters. But no matter if I add the exact Repository name or names any Repo is still picked up for loading.

## Questions

What are my options to ignore the repositories and maybe also future classes, when I run WebMvc tests? I assume this should be achievable using excludeFilters, but it seems I'm missing something.

I've searched around and looked into the documentation, but it seems the details on how to set up excludeFilters properly evades me. I welcome any pointers here.

Comment: Trick: place the web test  in the same package as the controller,, separated from "data" packages...

Comment: Yes, at some point I'll separate types of classes. But I'm lazy and it would be good to be able to exclude at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled over a solution after having found some [proper description over the options](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-componentscan-filter-type#regex_filter) (Baeldung) and chose regex as all source files have "Repository" as part of the name:

```
@WebMvcTest(excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
type = FilterType.REGEX, 
pattern = ".*[Repository]")}
)
```